# Accessing personal folders from iPads using WebDav on Lion Server 10.7

Tags: active-directory, webdav, ipad, lion

I am setting up Lion server so users on an Active Directory network can access webdav folders from iPads.

I have got this working fine when accessing a shared multi user folder.

I want users to also be able to access their own personal folders, with no one else being able to access the folder.

I can share the Users folder out to Active Directory groups but this will give each user access to other users folders how can I fix this without manually creating each folder and sharing it to each user?

Comment: It is probably obvious to other OSX users, but what daemon is OSX using?  Apache, or something else?

Comment: Not actually an OSX user :) I am pretty sure its based on Apache though